# Trying to Understand why it can't "convert string to integer" (Ruby histogram iterating over the hash)

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I've been stuck on this Codeacademy exercise for the last 45 minutes or so. None of the proposed solutions from the Q&A forum worked. The code is as follows.

```
puts "Type something profound please"
text = gets.chomp
words = text.split

frequencies = Hash.new 0
frequencies = frequencies.sort_by {|x,y| y}
words.each {|word| frequencies[word] += 1}
frequencies = frequencies.sort_by{|x,y| y}.reverse
puts word +" " + frequencies.to_s
frequencies.each do |word, frequencies|   

end
```

Why can't it convert the string into an integer? What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: You need to show your input data and expected output.

Comment: I just started Ruby less than a week ago. I'm not sure how to do that. Can you elaborate or maybe give another quick example to help enlighten me?

Comment: @user3324987 We don't know, what your goal is.. So I asked you to create a new question.

Comment: Good point. Ok, I'll do that now.

Comment: When you create a question, you need to give us sample input and what you expect the output to look like, otherwise we have to guess at both, often frustrating us, and you.

Answer (score 3):

[`sort_by { |obj| block } → array`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by) is clear.

`frequencies.sort_by {|x,y| y}` gives you an array. `frequencies` is an array, not a hash. Thus in `words.each {|word| frequencies[word] += 1}`, `frequencies[word]` *raises an exception*, as `frequencies` is an array, and elements of an array is accessed via the integer index, but you tried with **string** `word`. `words = text.split`, so `words` holds array of strings.

Comment: Not bad. < 60 seconds.

Comment: Ok, I get what you're saying conceptually, but I'm still not sure of the best practical application. So which line of code needs to be changed? I still don't know how to make this work.

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to add a concrete example to help out here.

```
puts "Type something profound please"
text = gets.chomp
words = text.split
frequencies = {}
```

In Ruby, it is more typical to declare a hash with {} than with Hash.new, but either works.

```
words.each do |word|
    if frequencies.has_key?(word)
        frequencies[word] += 1
    else
        frequencies[word] = 1
    end
end
```

The above simply iterates over the words array to build out the frequencies hash (hash[key] = value). It can also be abbreviated as:

```
words.each {|word| frequencies.has_key?(word) ? frequencies[word] += 1 : frequencies[word] = 1 }
```

Also, it is helpful if you provide your desired output/return value. I'm assuming you're wanting a hash of word => integer (as shown below), but this could easily be tweaked if you want some other format or sorting.

```
{
       "my" => 1,
    "array" => 1,
       "of" => 1,
    "words" => 2,
     "with" => 1,
     "some" => 1,
"repeating" => 1
}
```